# Resize font in legend below \tiny

Tags: pgfplots, fontsize, legend

I have small graph in my presentation (I have to). To adjust the size of the legend, I have to use very small legend. But \tiny is not enought.

Here is a MWE :

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{etex}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{data.dat}
x,y
1,2
2,3
3,4
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        legend style={font=\tiny},
        xlabel={x},
        ylabel={y},
        width=4cm, height=3cm,
        ymin=0,
        xmin=0,
        xmajorgrids, xminorgrids, ymajorgrids,
    ]   
    \addplot table [col sep=comma]{data.dat};
    \addlegendentry{Test Test Test};
    \end{axis}  
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Giving this :

[image]

Comment: Do you want the legend to be read only with a magnifying glass? ;o)

Comment: I exagerated the problem to show you ^^

Answer (score 16, accepted):

beamer has the additional font switch `\Tiny` that will give you a smaller size than `\tiny` (if your current font supports this size); if this is not enough, you can use `\fontsize{<size>}{<baselineskip>}\selectfont` with appropriate values.

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{etex}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
%\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{data.dat}
x,y
1,2
2,3
3,4
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        legend style={font=\fontsize{4}{5}\selectfont},
        xlabel={x},
        ylabel={y},
        width=4cm, height=3cm,
        ymin=0,
        xmin=0,
        xmajorgrids, xminorgrids, ymajorgrids,
    ]   
    \addplot table [col sep=comma]{data.dat};
    \addlegendentry{Test Test Test};
    \end{axis}  
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It looks like like it's impossible to have less than 5 in size. So I don't manage to go really down in size. Maybe there is really a limit...

Comment: @zeslayer As I mentioned in my answer, it all depends on the font you are using; wheter it is scalable to the desired font size or not. For example, using the `lmodern` fonts: `\usepackage{lmodern}` you can get sizes of `1pt` with no problem.

Comment: Ok. The the problem is my font ! Thanks a lot. Problem solved.