# pgfplots: Scaling legend font size

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

There are a few posts that ask and answer how to scale the legend font size. For example,

- [pgfplots: alignment and size of math in legend](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48620/pgfplots-alignment-and-size-of-math-in-legend)
- [Resize font in legend below \tiny](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/257709/resize-font-in-legend-below-tiny)

However, these rely upon using the command:

```
 legend style={font=\tiny}
```

I'd like to re-scale the legend fonts (or perhaps even the entire legend) using a `scale = 0.5` command (or similar), similar to how you would re-scale a node. I asked a similar question here about re-scaling the font size of axes labels, but I could not get the same solution to work for the legend (that is, simply changing `font=` to `style=` does not seem to work.

- [How do I change the font size of the labels along the axes in pgfplots [using scaling]?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/255336/how-do-i-change-the-font-size-of-the-labels-along-the-axes-in-pgfplots-using-sc)

I attach a minimal example below:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[legend image post style={mark=*}]

\addplot+[mark=*, color=blue, very thin, only marks, mark size=0.8pt]{-x*(x-2)};
\addlegendentry{Measurement}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

which produces

[image: legend example]

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Something like:

```
[...]
    \begin{axis}[legend style={nodes={scale=0.5, transform shape}}, 
        legend image post style={mark=*}]
[...]
```

The "style" `nodes` of the legend will be applied to all the nodes created to generate the legend box.

[image: Screenshot for the above snippet]

(BTW, you should add a `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}` to your code, or at least something like that, to avoid problems with ticks labels in the future).

Complete code (for reference):

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[legend style={nodes={scale=0.5, transform shape}}, 
        legend image post style={mark=*}]

\addplot+[mark=*, color=blue, very thin, only marks, mark size=0.8pt]{-x*(x-2)};
\addlegendentry{Measurement}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This seems to work well!