# Resizing TikZ figure created in R that contains legend

Tags: tikz-pgf, r, scale

I've shifted through several similar questions (such as [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/301092/pgfplots-scaling-legend-font-size) and [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26846/how-to-scale-a-tikzpicture-including-texts)), but couldn't find an answer.

I'm trying to rescale a plot produced in R, using the tikzDevice library, but I'm having trouble with the legend. I understand that the scalebox and resizebox commands from the graphicx package don't work on text within a TikZ picture, but don't know how to sort that (note: I'd like that my R and tex scripts would run smoothly, without any further changes on the file generated through the tikzDevice command).

### .tex file

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!htbp]
  \caption{Example}
  \centering
  \resizebox{1\textwidth}{!}{\input{counts}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

### R script

```
set.seed(62442)
# Generating example data
mat = matrix(round(runif(32, 0, 30)), nr = 4)

# Vector of colors 
cols = gray(c(0, 1 / 6, 1 / 6 * 2, 1 / 6 * 3))

# Calling tikz to export to latex
library(tikzDevice)

# Plotting
tikz("counts.tex")
barplot(mat, beside = T, col = cols, ylim = c(0, 40), xlab = "", axes = F, width = 1, space = c(.2, 5))
box()   
legend("topright", c("First var", "Second var", "Third var", "Fourth var"), lty = rep(1, 4), lwd = rep(10, 4), col = cols)
axis(2, las = 1)
title(main = "", xlab = "Counts", ylab = "Observations", outer = T)
dev.off()
```

### TikZ figure

```
% Created by tikzDevice version 0.10.1 on 2017-10-01 16:26:13
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1pt,y=1pt]
\definecolor{fillColor}{RGB}{255,255,255}
\path[use as bounding box,fill=fillColor,fill opacity=0.00] (0,0) rectangle (505.89,505.89);
\begin{scope}
\path[clip] (  0.00,  0.00) rectangle (505.89,505.89);
\definecolor{drawColor}{RGB}{0,0,0}
\definecolor{fillColor}{RGB}{0,0,0}

\path[draw=drawColor,line width= 0.4pt,line join=round,line cap=round,fill=fillColor] ( 65.18, 61.20) rectangle ( 70.75,130.41);
\definecolor{fillColor}{gray}{0.17}

\path[draw=drawColor,line width= 0.4pt,line join=round,line cap=round,fill=fillColor] ( 71.86, 61.20) rectangle ( 77.42,199.62);
\definecolor{fillColor}{RGB}{85,85,85}

\path[draw=drawColor,line width= 0.4pt,line join=round,line cap=round,fill=fillColor] ( 78.54, 61.20) rectangle ( 84.10,179.85);
\definecolor{fillColor}{RGB}{128,128,128}

\path[draw=drawColor,line width= 0.4pt,line join=round,line cap=round,fill=fillColor] ( 85.21, 61.20) rectangle ( 90.78,169.96);
\definecolor{fillColor}{RGB}{0,0,0}

\path[draw=drawColor,line width= 0.4pt,line join=round,line cap=round,fill=fillColor] (118.60, 61.20) rectangle (124.16,150.19);
\definecolor{fillColor}{gray}{0.17}

\path[draw=drawColor,line width= 0.4pt,line join=round,line cap=round,fill=fillColor] (125.28, 61.20) rectangle (130.84,328.16);
\definecolor{fillColor}{RGB}{85,85,85}

\path[draw=drawColor,line width= 0.4pt,line join=round,line cap=round,fill=fillColor] (131.95, 61.20) rectangle (137.52,219.40);
\definecolor{fillColor}{RGB}{128,128,128}

\path[draw=drawColor,line width= 0.4pt,line join=round,line cap=round,fill=fillColor] (138.63, 61.20) rectangle (144.20, 61.20);
\definecolor{fillColor}{RGB}{0,0,0}

\path[draw=drawColor,line width= 0.4pt,line join=round,line cap=round,fill=fillColor] (172.02, 61.20) rectangle (177.58,278.72);
\definecolor{fillColor}{gray}{0.17}

\path[draw=drawColor,line width= 0.4pt,line join=round,line cap=round,fill=fillColor] (178.70, 61.20) rectangle (184.26,100.75);
\definecolor{fillColor}{RGB}{85,85,85}

\path[draw=drawColor,line width= 0.4pt,line join=round,line cap=round,fill=fillColor] (185.37, 61.20) rectangle (190.94,140.30);
\definecolor{fillColor}{RGB}{128,128,128}

\path[draw=drawColor,line width= 0.4pt,line join=round,line cap=round,fill=fillColor] (192.05, 61.20) rectangle (197.62, 90.86);
\definecolor{fillColor}{RGB}{0,0,0}

\path[draw=drawColor,line width= 0.4pt,line join=round,line cap=round,fill=fillColor] (225.44, 61.20) rectangle (231.00,120.52);
\definecolor{fillColor}{gray}{0.17}

\path[draw=drawColor,line width= 0.4pt,line join=round,line cap=round,fill=fillColor] (232.11, 61.20) rectangle (237.68, 80.97);
\definecolor{fillColor}{RGB}{85,85,85}

\path[draw=drawColor,line width= 0.4pt,line join=round,line cap=round,fill=fillColor] (238.79, 61.20) rectangle (244.36,258.94);
\definecolor{fillColor}{RGB}{128,128,128}

\path[draw=drawColor,line width= 0.4pt,line join=round,line cap=round,fill=fillColor] (245.47, 61.20) rectangle (251.03,110.64);
\definecolor{fillColor}{RGB}{0,0,0}

\path[draw=drawColor,line width= 0.4pt,line join=round,line cap=round,fill=fillColor] (278.86, 61.20) rectangle (284.42, 90.86);
\definecolor{fillColor}{gray}{0.17}

\path[draw=drawColor,line width= 0.4pt,line join=round,line cap=round,fill=fillColor] (285.53, 61.20) rectangle (291.10, 80.97);
\definecolor{fillColor}{RGB}{85,85,85}

\path[draw=drawColor,line width= 0.4pt,line join=round,line cap=round,fill=fillColor] (292.21, 61.20) rectangle (297.78,229.28);
\definecolor{fillColor}{RGB}{128,128,128}

\path[draw=drawColor,line width= 0.4pt,line join=round,line cap=round,fill=fillColor] (298.89, 61.20) rectangle (304.45,169.96);
\definecolor{fillColor}{RGB}{0,0,0}

\path[draw=drawColor,line width= 0.4pt,line join=round,line cap=round,fill=fillColor] (332.27, 61.20) rectangle (337.84,160.07);
\definecolor{fillColor}{gray}{0.17}

\path[draw=drawColor,line width= 0.4pt,line join=round,line cap=round,fill=fillColor] (338.95, 61.20) rectangle (344.52,189.73);
\definecolor{fillColor}{RGB}{85,85,85}

\path[draw=drawColor,line width= 0.4pt,line join=round,line cap=round,fill=fillColor] (345.63, 61.20) rectangle (351.19,130.41);
\definecolor{fillColor}{RGB}{128,128,128}

\path[draw=drawColor,line width= 0.4pt,line join=round,line cap=round,fill=fillColor] (352.31, 61.20) rectangle (357.87,328.16);
\definecolor{fillColor}{RGB}{0,0,0}

\path[draw=drawColor,line width= 0.4pt,line join=round,line cap=round,fill=fillColor] (385.69, 61.20) rectangle (391.26,209.51);
\definecolor{fillColor}{gray}{0.17}

\path[draw=drawColor,line width= 0.4pt,line join=round,line cap=round,fill=fillColor] (392.37, 61.20) rectangle (397.94,189.73);
\definecolor{fillColor}{RGB}{85,85,85}

\path[draw=drawColor,line width= 0.4pt,line join=round,line cap=round,fill=fillColor] (399.05, 61.20) rectangle (404.61,308.38);
\definecolor{fillColor}{RGB}{128,128,128}

\path[draw=drawColor,line width= 0.4pt,line join=round,line cap=round,fill=fillColor] (405.73, 61.20) rectangle (411.29,110.64);
\definecolor{fillColor}{RGB}{0,0,0}

\path[draw=drawColor,line width= 0.4pt,line join=round,line cap=round,fill=fillColor] (439.11, 61.20) rectangle (444.68,278.72);
\definecolor{fillColor}{gray}{0.17}

\path[draw=drawColor,line width= 0.4pt,line join=round,line cap=round,fill=fillColor] (445.79, 61.20) rectangle (451.35,130.41);
\definecolor{fillColor}{RGB}{85,85,85}

\path[draw=drawColor,line width= 0.4pt,line join=round,line cap=round,fill=fillColor] (452.47, 61.20) rectangle (458.03,278.72);
\definecolor{fillColor}{RGB}{128,128,128}

\path[draw=drawColor,line width= 0.4pt,line join=round,line cap=round,fill=fillColor] (459.14, 61.20) rectangle (464.71,328.16);
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}
\path[clip] (  0.00,  0.00) rectangle (505.89,505.89);
\definecolor{drawColor}{RGB}{0,0,0}

\node[text=drawColor,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  1.00] at ( 77.98, 39.60) {0};

\node[text=drawColor,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  1.00] at (131.40, 39.60) {1};

\node[text=drawColor,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  1.00] at (184.82, 39.60) {2};

\node[text=drawColor,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  1.00] at (238.24, 39.60) {3};

\node[text=drawColor,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  1.00] at (291.65, 39.60) {4};

\node[text=drawColor,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  1.00] at (345.07, 39.60) {5};

\node[text=drawColor,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  1.00] at (398.49, 39.60) {6};

\node[text=drawColor,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  1.00] at (451.91, 39.60) {7};
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}
\path[clip] (  0.00,  0.00) rectangle (505.89,505.89);
\definecolor{drawColor}{RGB}{0,0,0}

\path[draw=drawColor,line width= 0.4pt,line join=round,line cap=round] ( 49.20, 61.20) --
    (480.69, 61.20) --
    (480.69,456.69) --
    ( 49.20,456.69) --
    ( 49.20, 61.20);
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}
\path[clip] ( 49.20, 61.20) rectangle (480.69,456.69);
\definecolor{drawColor}{RGB}{0,0,0}

\path[draw=drawColor,line width= 0.4pt,line join=round,line cap=round] (392.67,456.69) rectangle (480.69,396.69);

\path[draw=drawColor,line width= 4.0pt,line join=round,line cap=round] (401.67,444.69) -- (419.67,444.69);
\definecolor{drawColor}{gray}{0.17}

\path[draw=drawColor,line width= 4.0pt,line join=round,line cap=round] (401.67,432.69) -- (419.67,432.69);
\definecolor{drawColor}{RGB}{85,85,85}

\path[draw=drawColor,line width= 4.0pt,line join=round,line cap=round] (401.67,420.69) -- (419.67,420.69);
\definecolor{drawColor}{RGB}{128,128,128}

\path[draw=drawColor,line width= 4.0pt,line join=round,line cap=round] (401.67,408.69) -- (419.67,408.69);
\definecolor{drawColor}{RGB}{0,0,0}

\node[text=drawColor,anchor=base west,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  1.00] at (428.67,441.25) {First var};

\node[text=drawColor,anchor=base west,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  1.00] at (428.67,429.25) {Second var};

\node[text=drawColor,anchor=base west,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  1.00] at (428.67,417.25) {Third var};

\node[text=drawColor,anchor=base west,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  1.00] at (428.67,405.25) {Fourth var};
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}
\path[clip] (  0.00,  0.00) rectangle (505.89,505.89);
\definecolor{drawColor}{RGB}{0,0,0}

\path[draw=drawColor,line width= 0.4pt,line join=round,line cap=round] ( 49.20, 61.20) -- ( 49.20,456.69);

\path[draw=drawColor,line width= 0.4pt,line join=round,line cap=round] ( 49.20, 61.20) -- ( 43.20, 61.20);

\path[draw=drawColor,line width= 0.4pt,line join=round,line cap=round] ( 49.20,160.07) -- ( 43.20,160.07);

\path[draw=drawColor,line width= 0.4pt,line join=round,line cap=round] ( 49.20,258.94) -- ( 43.20,258.94);

\path[draw=drawColor,line width= 0.4pt,line join=round,line cap=round] ( 49.20,357.82) -- ( 43.20,357.82);

\path[draw=drawColor,line width= 0.4pt,line join=round,line cap=round] ( 49.20,456.69) -- ( 43.20,456.69);

\node[text=drawColor,anchor=base east,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  1.00] at ( 37.20, 57.76) {0};

\node[text=drawColor,anchor=base east,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  1.00] at ( 37.20,156.63) {10};

\node[text=drawColor,anchor=base east,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  1.00] at ( 37.20,255.50) {20};

\node[text=drawColor,anchor=base east,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  1.00] at ( 37.20,354.37) {30};

\node[text=drawColor,anchor=base east,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  1.00] at ( 37.20,453.25) {40};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Have you tried adding `transform canvas={scale=0.5}` to your `tikzpicture` environment?

Comment: @Andrew, yes. Doesn't work.

Comment: Being a little more specific, if I include the transform canvas argument, the plot spills over on to the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure of how should be the final image that you want (rscale what and how?), but I am quite sure that your are doing in the hard way.

Consider this `yourbarplot.Rnw` where the image is scaled to the 90% of the text width:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[2]
<<Example,echo=F,dev='tikz', fig.cap="Use R with \\LaTeX{}", fig.align='center', out.width='.9\\linewidth'>>=
set.seed(62442)
mat = matrix(round(runif(32, 0, 30)), nr = 4)
cols = gray(c(0, 1 / 6, 1 / 6 * 2, 1 / 6 * 3))
library(tikzDevice)
par(mar=c(5,6,.5,4)) # adjust as needed
barplot(mat, beside = T, las = 1, col = cols, ylim = c(0, 40), 
    xlab = "Counts",  ylab = "Observations", width = 1, space = c(.2, 5))
legend("topright", c("First var", "Second var", "Third var", "Fourth var"), lty = rep(1, 4), lwd = rep(10, 4), col = cols)
@
\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

This is is compilable directly without any other user action that open in Rstudio and push the "Compile" button (unless you have change the default "knitr" by "Sweave" in the preferences"). The result:

> [image: mwe]

Comment: Seems rather cumbersome to do this for all the plots in the paper, especially when I need to make R scripts available for reproducibility.

Comment: @LucasDeAbreuMaia Cumbersome? Just the contrary!  The greatest strength of  knitr is allow **real reproducible research** and **literate programming**. No need to translate (correctly?) every R output to the LaTeX document. As R code change, so will the final PDF, no possibility of outdated/wrong results in the PDF.  Are you 110% sure with your actual routine? All is perfectly traceable in a single file,  not only the R raw results, but also how they are "digested" and  interpreted *exactly*.  (...and even the R could be a bit simpler).

Comment: @LucasDeAbreuMaia Moreover, with  `knitr::purl("yourbarplot.Rnw")`  you can extract all the R code chunks  of the document, without LateX text, in `yourbarplot.R`.  The chunk options are passed as R comments, so you can still see how the R code was splitted in the .Rnw file.

Comment: I understand the advantage of using knitr, but I have good reason not to use RStudio: I'm blind and RStudio is inaccessible to my screen reader. Can I use your solution with R GUI?

Comment: @LucasDeAbreuMaia Then knitr is a must for you.  The .Rnw to .tex export  is done by R commands. Of course that it can done be in the R prompt: just `library(knitr); knit('yourbarblot.Rnw')` or without the R console,  just run  `Rscript -e "library(knitr); knit('my_sweave_file.Rnw')"` in the command line prompt. Then the .tex to .pdf  will be a job exclusive for the LaTeX engines as usual. Read https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/132724/11604.  My suggestion is make a executable script for these steps but beside this, search about Rmarkdown !!